# Como atribuir o retorno de strtok à um array de strings?

Tags: c

Galera, eu tava testando a função `strtok` só que tá dando esse problema de "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)".

Antes eu havia tentado fazer `strPtr [i] = strtok (str1, str2);` mas dava esse erro:

> "error: assignment to expression with array type error"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
char str1[] = "Teste de funcao que separa string em tokens";
char str2[] = " ";
char strPtr[10][10];


char *aux;
int i;
aux = strtok (str1, str2);
strcpy (strPtr[0], aux);
for (i = 1; strPtr[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    aux = strtok (NULL, str2);
    strcpy (strPtr[i], aux);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    puts(strPtr[i]);
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da Biblioteca Padrão C, [Seção ¶7.1.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4) (tradução feita por mim)

> Cada uma das seguintes afirmações aplica-se a menos que seja
>   explicitamente estabelecido o contrário nas descrições detalhadas que
>   se seguem: se um argumento para uma função tiver um valor inválido
>   (como [...] um ponteiro nulo [...]) [...] o comportamento é
>   indefinido.

Portanto, quando `aux` possuir o valor `NULL`, você vai encontrar um comportamento indefinido. Isso vai acontecer pois o seu laço de repetição não verifica tal situação.

Eu sugiro que você modifique o seu laço de repetição que alimenta seu *array* de *strings*. Algo como

```
for (char *aux = strtok(str1, str2); aux != NULL; aux = strtok(NULL, str2))
{
  ...
}
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/RoundProperNighthawk).

Comment: Ainda diria mais: independente dos comportamentos das funções `strcpy` e `strtok`, aquela laço na variável não inicializada está destinado a sempre incidir nesse erro, pois quase sempre a região de memória conterá lixo e nunca alcançará esse tal de `strPtr[i] == NULL`, portanto toda operação feita sobre `strPtr[i]` está sujeita a esse problema

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou agora! Você saberia me explicar porque quando eu declaro `char *aux` fora do `for` ela da esse warning  **"assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"** ?

Comment: @ThiagoRizzi estranho, eu movi a declaração para fora do `for` e compilou sem problemas. Tem certeza que essa foi sua única mudança?

Comment: @mercador Estranho que eu fui testar e funcionou agora, coisas estranhas acontecem na programação kkkk